# How to decode a TimeStamp from the firebase Firestore in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, codable

I am wanting to decode a TimeStamp (as defined by FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp in swift) by parsing the response from the firestore database.

The following code to parse from the server has the compiler telling me:

> instance method 'decode(_:forKey:)' requires that 'Timestamp' conform
>   to 'Decodable'

```
 created = try container.decode(FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.self, forKey: .created)
```

also I am unable to encode (to save locally or send to the server) with the following line:

```
try container.encode(created, forKey: .created)
```

compiler says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Timestamp' to expected argument type
>   'String'

A full copy-paste is below

Also, it appears the timestamp is a dictionary, not an integer, because when I try to decode the timestamp as an integer, I get the error:

```
Expected to decode Int but found a dictionary instead.
```

but we all know that [String:Any] (i.e a dictionary) is not possible to decode.

```
import FirebaseFirestore

class SomeClassToParseFromFirestoresDatabase: Codable
{

  var created = FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.init(date: Date())

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
  {
    case created
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
  {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    do
    {
      try container.encode(created, forKey: .created)
    }
    catch let error
    {
      print("error encoding to server or locally: \(error) ")
    }
  }


  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
  {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)


    do
    {
      created = try container.decode(FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.self, forKey: .created)
    }
    catch 
    {
      print("error getting 'created' from server: \(error) ")
    }
  }
}
```

Below is an example of how to parse a response from an https.callable firestore function (which just return JSON) - and to use the custom response class to parse a timestamp in the response (and also store a timestamp in the class)

```
func getChatUsers( _ done: @escaping (ChatUsersResponse) -> ())
  {
    let response     = ChatUsersResponse()
    response.success = true

    let functions    = Functions.functions()

    functions.httpsCallable("getChatUsers").call
    { (result, error) in

      if let error = error as NSError?
      {
        response.success = false
        response.message = error.localizedDescription

        done(response)
      }
      else if let result = result,
        let data = result.data as? [String:Any],
        let users = data["users"]
      {
        do
        {
          let nsdata     = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: users, options: .prettyPrinted)
          **response.users = try JSONDecoder().decode([SomeClassToParseFromFirestoresDatabase].self, from:nsdata)**
          done(response)
        }
        catch let error
        {          
          response.success = false
          response.message = error.localizedDescription
          done(response)
          return
        }
      }
      else
      {
        response.success = false
        response.message = "Server responded with no error, but no users either"
        done(response)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the code in the question is doing but maybe if we just simplify the process, it will help.

Here's a function to write a Firestore Timestamp to a 'timestamp' collection, each document will have a unique documentID and a child field of 'stamp'

```
func writeTimestampAction() {
    let now = Date()
    let stamp = Timestamp(date: now)

    let docRef = self.db.collection("timestamps").document()
    docRef.setData( [
        "stamp": stamp
    ])
}
```

and then a function to read all of the the timestamps from that collection and output them to the console in a yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
func readTimestampAction() {
    self.db.collection("timestamps").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                if let stamp = document.get("stamp") {
                    let title = document.documentID
                    let ts = stamp as! Timestamp
                    let aDate = ts.dateValue()
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
                    let formattedTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: aDate)
                    print(title, formattedTimeZoneStr)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit

He's an activity class that could be passed the Firestore snapshot

```
class ActivityClass {
    var activity_name = ""
    var activity_date: Timestamp?

    convenience init(withDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        if let stamp = withDoc.get("stamp") {
            self.activity_date = stamp as? Timestamp
        }
    }
}
```

and when you're retrieving the data from Firestore just do this

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
   let myActivity = ActivityClass(withDoc: document)
   //do something with myActivity
```

Comment: thanks. I'm wanting to do the opposite (read a firestore timestamp into a local class from an https callable response) - I updated my post

Comment: @aman The opposite of what? This answer demonstrates how to both *write* a timestamp as well as *read* a time stamp? If the timestamp exists, just use the second part of the answer and once you read the timestamp with `let ts = stamp as! Timestamp`, store it in your class.

Comment: sorry, I see now. I guess I don't understand how to translate what you wrote - which parses the document to Swift's native Codable Protocol

Comment: @aman I think my question is why are you working with codable protocols? Why not just pass the snapshot returned from Firestore to the class? That make may the code easier to read and more expandable and maintainable. I updated my answer with a suggestion. Maybe it's not the direction you want to go but it's pretty clean.

Comment: Thanks Jay. The response comes from a callable function in the cloud (not a local client SDK using firebase 'db') - so I need to parse the response from NSData. Also, I'm working with protocols because I have a data model that keeps all response homogenous. Which just means - all responses have 'success' (true or false) 'message' (to display the error message if success==false), and then some data which can be any key. Also for every response I save the data locally and then later unpack that data into the UI.

Comment: @aman Ok, here's my confusion; your question states you want to decode a Firebase timestamp but in your comment here you're stating that data isn't coming from Firebase, it's coming from NSData returned from a callable function in the cloud. I think my answer demonstrates how to work with data from Firebase (per the question) and maybe the NSData decodable is a separate issue/question?

Comment: @aman Did you ever figure this out? I also need to decode a Firestore timestamp and can't figure it out. Seems like no one else on the internet is trying to do this.

Comment: @BryanDeemer Firebase added support for Codable objects in their SDK in 2018. A Timestamp is read and assigned to a Codable object property like any other property. If you have a coding question please post the question as it's a good topic! Also, check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swift2go/swifty-firebase-apis-ka-ching-part-1-c7f2e6fb9459) about implementing codable in Firestore

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do 2 things.

The first thing was to 'set' my date on the server-side by using timeStamp's 'toString()' - even though it looks like a string by default, timestamp is not a string and the client parses an empty dictionary.

Then I was able to take that string and convert it to a date with the following date format

```
  let d = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .created)
  //example: Fri Apr 26 2019 17:25:22
  let index = d.index(d.endIndex, offsetBy: -15) 
  let abc = d[..<index]

  let dateFormatter        = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"


  if let d = dateFormatter.date(from:String(abc))
  {
    created = d
  }
```